# Ubuntu Studio LTS 22.04 - How to get MOTU Midi USB interfaces to work?

Tags: interface, midi, motu

Specifically looking for how to get my MOTU Midi Express, Midi Express 128 and Micro Lite USB midi interfaces to work.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all so that we are not guessing in helping you out and giving you information that you have already tried?  I did a quick look around the internet and found a driver https://github.com/vampirefrog/motu and it also explains why there is no Linux drivers.

Comment: @Terrance Well I certainly haven't tried a whole lot, mainly since I've been using Linux for only about a week now and didn't know what I needed to be looking for as far as the internal system goes.  I did find that same github/vampirefrog driver but I really wasn't able to figure out how to get it installed. I'd be willing to give that a try but was hoping that there might be something I missed that is natively available, newer or more straightforward for the beginner me.

Comment: The only supported MOTU USB MIDI device is the Fastlane (because it's the only one using a protocol somewhat similar to that of class-compliant USB MIDI devices).

Comment: Thank you both.  The Fastlane is no longer in production and even if I went the used gear route it is too limited.  Guess I'll try to figure out the install process for this older driver or have to go back to the previous OS.